# How can I add support for .flac files in SoX?

Tags: macos, audio, homebrew, flac

I want SoX to record audio in .flac files. When I do:

```
rec -t flac ~/Desktop/myrec.flac
```

…it gives the following error:

```
rec FAIL formats: no handler for given file type `flac'
```

I have installed SoX from 'brew' and and I do have flac 1.2.1 installed.

I have gone though man pages at http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.pdf but did not get the information that I am looking for.

How can I add support for .flac files?

I am on OS X 10.9.3

Comment: Today, when I installed `sox` from Homebrew (no extra options), FLAC support just worked out of the box.

Answer (score 35):

Keeping it simple.

Removing it using brew like so :

```
brew remove sox
```

Then installing it again with specific options, like so, did the trick for me:

```
brew install sox --with-lame --with-flac --with-libvorbis
```

You may want to remove the `--with-lame` option if you won't be using MP3s, or the `--with-libvorbis` if you won't be using OGG.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you, this also solves sox FAIL formats: no handler for detected file type `vorbis' . How strange those are not in by default.

Comment: You can also just `brew reinstall` instead of `brew remove`, `brew install`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
brew remove libogg flac sox
brew update
brew doctor
brew install libogg flac
brew install sox
```

This should recompile sox with libogg and flac present, and it will then find the FLAC support.

```
~$ brew info sox
sox: stable 14.4.1
http://sox.sourceforge.net/
/usr/local/Cellar/sox/14.4.1_1 (15 files, 2.1M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/sox.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: libpng ✔, mad ✔
Optional: opencore-amr ✘, libvorbis ✔, flac ✔, libsndfile ✔, libao ✘, lame ✔
==> Options
--with-flac
    Build with flac support
--with-lame
    Build with lame support
--with-libao
    Build with libao support
--with-libsndfile
    Build with libsndfile support
--with-libvorbis
    Build with libvorbis support
--with-opencore-amr
    Build with opencore-amr support
```

Comment: I have tried above steps. But still the same issue.

Comment: here is my output of brew info sox
sox: stable 14.4.1
http://sox.sourceforge.net/
/usr/local/Cellar/sox/14.4.1_1 (15 files, 2.0M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/sox.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: libpng ✔, mad ✔
Optional: opencore-amr ✘, libvorbis ✘, flac ✔, libsndfile ✘, libao ✘, lame ✔
==> Options
--with-flac
 Build with flac support
--with-lame
 Build with lame support
--with-libao
 Build with libao support
--with-libsndfile
 Build with libsndfile support
--with-libvorbis
.
.
.
.

Comment: When I do the same, the only difference is that I have libsndfile and libvorbis as well. rec is working for me to create a .flac file. What happens if you repeat the steps above, but also install vorbis and libsndfile? `brew install libogg flac libsndfile libvorbis`

Comment: Following EgregiousClam's instructions did not work for me the first time around because trying to remove libogg failed with 'Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/libogg'. I did not pay much attention at the time and gave it another shot, now converting from FLAC does work. -- In other words: make sure the remove command does execute successfully (or you could try removing all three programs with separate `brew remove` commands.)